# Managing View Controller's on Rootview Controller like Subview in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

How you can add a child ViewController into Master View Controller ?

I have one RootviewController as the main menu of the game, with 4 Other view controllers like settingViewController, helpviewController, etc. 
Currently all is working fine, with Push and pop method by changing the whole screen.

Now, I want to use them as follows: when I click on the highscore button, it simply adds a sub view to the screen (so not the whole screen, and not a popup because the highscore screen's size is small).

The Master-Controller should not be disabled or invisible, and also I can touch the other buttons on the Master view controller. Now, when i click the other buttons on Master-Controller (i.e Setting) then the highscore controller should be disabled and the setting controller should be visible.

How can I do this ? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a UIView object and add it inside your masterview controller, also just set the frame of UiView accordingly to HighScore screen size. When you click on the HighScore button just addSubview and when the close button is pressed just remove it from the SuperView. Also you can achieve this via hiding and unhiding the view as well.